# ffmpeg `palettegen` spits out a palette `paletteuse` can't use

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use a palette to improve gif rendering from MP4s, [as has been suggested](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html). However, I'm running in to a bizarre problem:

```
$ ffmpeg -v warning -i test.mp4 -vf "fps=15,scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen" -y /tmp/palette.png

$ ffmpeg -v warning -i /tmp/palette.png -i test.mp4 -lavfi paletteuse -y test.gif
[Parsed_paletteuse_0 @ 0x7f83a8c0eb20] Palette input must contain exactly 256 pixels. Specified input has 480x480=230400 pixels
```

`palettegen` seems to be spitting out a palette that `paletteuse` can't actually use. This would be less mystifying if the docs didn't specify that this is not the expected behavior:

> reserve_transparent
>
> Create a palette of 255 colors maximum and reserve the last one for transparency. Reserving the transparency color is useful for GIF optimization. If not set, the maximum of colors in the palette will be 256. You probably want to disable this option for a standalone image. Set by default.

So uh. What do? (For the record: OsX 10.12, ffmpeg 3.2.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paletteuse filter expects the 2nd input to be the palette. In your present command, since the inputs aren't explicitly labelled, the filter inducts the inputs in the order they're specified. So,

```
ffmpeg -v warning -i test.mp4 -i /tmp/palette.png -lavfi paletteuse -y test.gif
```

Comment: Ha! Wunderbar! Never even thought to check that :P Thanks!